# Mark a task as unread in Quire

Tags: quire-api

I can't seem to find any way in the Quire API doc to mark a task as unread (i.e. appearing with a red/orange dot next to it in the Quire app). If it does not exist, it would be a useful feature to implement in order to allow the user to detect a change made through the Quire API.

Best regards,
Rafaël

Answer (score 1):

The "unread" indicator behaves in the same way when using the quire-api/browser or mobile clients. It shows when a new task or comment was added by another user, through either UI or api.

Neither the UI nor the quire API have a function to explicitly control this status indicator.
So as of now it would not just be a "new/missing" api feature first, it's rather a new completely new Quire-Feature, which had to be implemented first. You can post your feedback and ideas in the [Quire Feedback project](https://quire.io/w/Quire_Feedbacks) (keyword 'orange dot') or send an email to info@quire.io / support@quire.io.

So as of now you can trigger this by adding a comment or add a new task via API.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is to add a new task and to set `asUser`as true as explained in https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task-id--projectId--post. Then, the task will be marked as unread